# Bootstrap menus overlap on IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7

I'm putting together a site using Bootstrap and html5shiv.js.

I've got two "navbar" divs, one above the other on the screen.  In Chrome, Firefox and IE9, they look and work fine.  On IE7 and IE8 (or rather, IE9 in IE8 mode), the dropdown menu on the top appears behind parts of the navbar below it.[image: Overlapping menus] In this picture, "Overview" on the top has a dropdown with three items ("Person", "RSS", "Wiki") and the navbar below it has one item "2013-01 rev" which is a dropdown and which is showing through the Overview dropdown panel, and a second active item "Step 1 - People" which is showing in front of the dropdown panel.

I checked with the IE9 developer tools, and it shows the z-index on the dropdown panel (the part that says "RSS" and "Wiki" is 1000, and there is no z-index on the one below it.  I've tried putting a z-index on the one below it, and it doesn't help.

Since jsfiddle doesn't seem to work on IE7, I've make a small subset of the page on http://xen1.xcski.com/tmp/ie7_problem.html that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Man, there sure are a lot of questions and other web sites talking about the z-index bug in IE7, but unfortunately all the suggestions I read don't really work for Bootstrap menus.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Francium123 unfortunately no. It happens in IE8 in "compatibility mode", which it sets itself into for intranet sites. Now I'm just trying to run out the clock until the corporate upgrade to IE10 happens.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. It looks like the suggestion below worked.

Comment: Great. I had multiple dropdowns overlapping each other, adding a z-index to each of them worked. Thanks!

Comment: I initially thought the answer below was wrong because I was trying to do it through a style sheet rather than an inline style, but it turns out I had the CSS wrong so it wasn't being applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a positive z-index value on the top nav (i.e. the one with Overview, Cart, Access Review, etc.).

```
<div id="top-bar" class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav" style="z-index:1;">...</ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav">...</ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```